# What is the ¬ symbol called on a British Windows keyboard?

Tags: symbols

What is the ¬ symbol on a British Windows keyboard called? You get to it by pressing Shift and the key left of the '1'.

[image: keyboard layout]

Comment: General reference result: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I'm aware, I've always seen this referred to as a **negation symbol**. That is its primary use: to negate a logical evaluation in formal logic.

[SoftwareEngineering.SE seems to agree with me:](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/290162/what-is-%C2%AC-called-and-what-is-it-for)

> The only use I've seen for the `¬` symbol is to represent negation in the context of formal logic. For instance, if `P` is the proposition "It will rain today", then `¬P` is the proposition "It will not rain today." I've also seen `~` used for this.

Also note the first comment in the linked post:

> That character is `U+00AC NOT SIGN` and is [one of the many notations for logical negation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation#Notation).

[Unicode does indeed list this character as "NOT SIGN"](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ac/index.htm), which is shorthand for "negation symbol".

Comment: So, was this symbol on typewriter keyboards in Britain before the days of home computers?  Before the days when a common person would know anything about symbolic logic?

Comment: I've also seen it called "EBCDIC NOT", because it was generally used on IBM mainframe computers (which used the EBCDIC character set), but not on minis and micros (which generally used ~ and the ASCII character set).

Comment: @GEdgar: Note that George Boole published The Mathematical Analysis of Logic in 1847, well ahead of the advent of home computers. However, [I can't see the symbol on any picture I've looked at, so far](https://www.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/05/xremington-typewriter-with-qwerty-layout.jpg.pagespeed.gp+jp+jw+pj+ws+js+rj+rp+rw+ri+cp+md.ic.l2G8N2QMIK.jpg). The fact that symbols like ½ are actually found on the typewriter makes me suspect that a typewriter's keys may have been tailored to fit a financial context, but not necessarily a mathematical or computational one.

Comment: @JeffZeitlin I believe this is why it's found on computer keyboards today. It was necessary on IBM mainframes running PL/I, and when IBM started making consumer keyboards they brought the same key set.

Comment: MS Word has this sign as "optional hyphen" but i don't know if this was the original meaning of this character, othe than the use in logic

Comment: @TroyHurts: seems unlikely to be the reason.  Wouldn't it be on US keyboards too?  And is it on XT keyboards?

Comment: Huh, in practice I’ve only ever seen this to be the ‘show hidden characters’-mode way of representing a manual line break. Never knew it was a negator…

Comment: @rjpond That's a good point about US keyboards. If I had to hazard a guess, perhaps the introduction of BS 4822 in 1980, against which UK keyboards are standardised, came at a time when IBM layouts with ¬ were more commonplace in the UK than the US, but trends continued to change in the US before the design we have today solidified. This is total conjecture, however.